# How to find if part of a string (or string) is inside of a list Python

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to see if "Sword" appears in inventory so I want it to trigger if like "Iron Sword" is in inventory or "Sword" in inventory.
I've tried several ways to do this like the one below but doing the 4 space indent is a pain for every line.

```
inventory = ['blahblahh blah']
def code():
   if "Sword" in inventory:
   #blah blah code
```

Comment: Does inventory just contain one string or is it multiple string elements?

Comment: multiple string, in my code it starts a blank list thats appended as the player goes

Comment: Great, trincots answer is correct then.

Comment: Okay thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your inventory is a list, you need to iterate over it, and then do you check on the found element(s):

```
def code(needle, inventory):
    for elem in inventory:
        if needle in elem:
            #blah blah code
            break

code("Sword", ['blahblahh blah', 'some other', 'my Sword'])
```

As shown above, it is better to pass your values as arguments.

Comment: Is elem just a placeholder name or does it hold some specific importance? I'm new to python and i don't really know if its like a special thing

Comment: It takes the value of the string inside `inventory`. If `inventory` has more than one string, `elem` will get the value of each of them: one per iteration. It is a normal variable.

Comment: You can use any name. elem is just an example, but doesn't have any special properties.